Weight of a monomial
I have a question for the mathematicians in affine algebraic geometry: Given an algebraically closed field $k$, we define the projective $n$-space as the quotient space $\mathbb{P}^n = (k^{n+1} - \{0_{k+1}\})/\sim$, where $(a_0,\cdots, a_n) \sim (b_0, \cdots,b_n)$ if $(a_0,\cdots, a_n) = ( \lambda b_0, \cdots,\lambda b_n)$, so how it makes sense?
Afterwards, we define a polynomial $f \in k[x_0,\cdots, x_n]$ as homogeneous if $f$ is a linear combination of monomials of total weight $d \in \mathbb{N}$, following the definition from Robin Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry" on page 9. I wonder if my understanding of the total weight of a polynomial is correct, wherein I interpret it as the sum of the exponents in each monomial.
Let $[a_0:\cdots:a_n]$ denote the equivalence class of $(a_0,\cdots, a_n)$. Then, we have the following definition:

A subset $Y$ of $\mathbb {P}^n$ is an algebraic set if there exists a set $T$ of homogeneous elements of $k[x_0,\cdots, x_n]$ such that $Y=Z(T)=\{[a_0:\cdots:a_n] \in \mathbb {P} |:f(a_0,\cdots, a_n) =0 \, \text{for all} \, f\in T\}$.

Now, onto the main question:
In the book "Numerical Semigroups and Applications" by Abdallah Assi and Pedro A. Garcia-Sanchez on page 60, the author considers the polynomial $F=y^n+a_1(x)y^{n-1}+\cdots +a_n(x)$ in the polynomial ring $k[x, y] = k[x][y]$ and defines $f_F(u, x, y) = u^nF(x/u, y/u)$. The author claims that $Z(h_F)$ is a projective curve. However, it's unclear whether $h_F$ is homogeneous, given my understanding of the weight of a polynomial.

$F\mapsto h_F$ is linear. So, just check it for monomials. If $F=x^ay^b$, then $h_F=u^d(x/u)^a(y/u)^b=u^{d-a-b}x^ay^b$ has total degree, or how you call it weight, $(d-a-b)+a+b=d$.

@ameg okay thank you very much, my mistake is that I check it just for y and forgetting $a_i(x) $.
